# Füllwort "traun" - Wo kommt das Wort her und was bedeutet es genau?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Ich kenne das Wort *traun* von früher; jetzt lese ich es in einer [Übersetzung des "Timaios" (Plato)](http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Platon/Timaios) auf zeno.org:

> Timaios: Traun, lieber Sokrates, tun doch das wohl alle, die auch nur ein wenig Überlegung besitzen: (...)
>
> Traun von der größten und mit vollem Rechte ruhmwürdigsten Tat von allen, welche diese Stadt vollbracht, von welcher aber wegen der Länge der Zeit und des Unterganges derer, die sie vollbracht haben, die Überlieferung sich nicht bis auf uns erhalten hat.(...)

Was genau bedeutet *traun* und woher stammt das Wort? Welcher zeitgenössischen Floskel würde das heute entsprechen? Passt vielleicht eine von denen:

`sieh mal,...`, `überhaupt,...`, `sowieso,...`

Comment: Interessante Frage! Das Wort *traun* war mir bisher völlig neu. Wird meines Wissens auch nicht mehr verwendet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aus [Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob Grimm und Wilhelm Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GT09266)

> **traun**, interj. , in wahrheit!, fürwahr!, wahrhaftig! herkunft und form.
>
> mhd. entriuwen, triuwen, mnd. entruwen, truwen, trouwen, mnl. trouwen, neunl. trouwens in gleicher bedeutung. ahd. nicht bezeugt, doch steht bei Notker häufig (achtzehnmal) triuwo atqui, certe, das offenbar das genaue singularische gegenstück zu dem dat. plur. mhd. triuwen ist, vgl. Graff 5, 466. adverb. wird dieses triuwo schwerlich sein, da es das adj. triuwi ahd. so gut wie gar nicht, und besonders bei Notker nicht gibt, [s. DWB treu](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&bookref=22,243,56), teil 11, 1, 2, sp. 246.

Und kurz und leserlich:

> **[traun](http://universal_lexikon.deacademic.com/128825/traun!)**! 〈veraltet; noch poet.〉 wahrhaftig!, fürwahr; mhd. entriuwen „in Treue, in Wahrheit“; → [treu](http://universal_lexikon.deacademic.com/3062/treu)

Auch verwandt mit "[trauen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GT08402)":

> trauen [...] mhd. trûwen, triuwen;

Und laut dem [Schwäbisches Wörterbuch mit etymologischen und historischen Anmerkungen](http://books.google.de/books?id=YYASAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=traun%20etymologie%20-donau&source=bl&ots=X1TRqMGVZ7&sig=Og-5JEfuHRxI12IidBb53VF8gbc&hl=de&sa=X&ei=uuL_T8fNEorHswb5_pDtBg&ved=0CEkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=traun%20etymologie%20-donau&f=false):

[image]

> "wahrlich" [...] Ableitung: "bei Treue", "bei meiner Treu"

Finally, the [DUDEN](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/traun):

> Gebrauch: gehoben veraltet
>
> Bedeutung: in der Tat!
>
> Synonyme: fürwahr, ungelogen

Comment: Ah, danke! Das liest sich überzeugend. In den heutigen Sprachgebrauch übertragen also z.B. "Echt!(...)" oder so...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Schlicht "In der Tat". Oder "Wohl wahr"; aber ich denke das "Echt" eher als Frage als als Aussage verwendet wird. (OMG, was für ein Satz..., es lebe das denn)

Comment: Ja, das klingt alles sehr gut. Herzlichen Dank. Ich mache mal das "akzeptieren-Häkchen

Comment: Wahrlich, wahrlich, ich sage Euch - auch ich kenn Traun nur von "Vertraun", "Zutraun" und Traunstein in Tirol.

Answer (score 6):

**traun** Interjektion - 
nach "Friedrich Kluge, Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache, Berlin, 20. Auflage 1967:

> Dem mhd.[mittelhochdeutsch] *entriuwen* 'in Treuen, in Wahrheit', das in unbetonter Stellung die erste Silbe verliert wie 'mitten', 'weg', 'zwischen', entspricht md.[mitteldeutsch] *truwen, trun*. In der Form   t r a u n  ...  ist es ein Lieblingswort Luthers ...durch den es schriftsprachlich wird mit *au* für mhd. *iuw* wie 'brauen', 'graulen','kauen'; vgl: Naumann, Naumburg, Nauheim, Fauerbach.

Anders gesagt: In "traun" steckt das germanisch-englische "true" "wahr". Es kann als Floskel gelten, wo man um Zustimmung ("nicht wahr?") bittet.